# Fancybox - Atualizar parent depois de fechar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

Estou usando um Fancybox iframe onde quando o usuario confirma uma pergunta quero que atualize o conteúdo da página original após o sucesso em um ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'excluir_foto2.asp',
        data: {cod: cod},
        success: function () {

            parent.$("#Itemwookmark" + '<%=id_wookmark%>').fadeOut(1000, function () {
                parent.$("#Itemwookmark" + '<%=id_wookmark%>').remove();
                parent.wookmark.initItems();
                parent.wookmark.layout(true);
                parent.$.fancybox.getInstance().close();
            });
        }
    });
```

Mas atualmente, para funcionar, tive que colocar para remover o item dentro do Wookmark, atualizar o Wookmark e só depois chamar o método .close() para fechar o fancybox.

Existe alguma maneira de eu fechar fancybox primeiro e só depois remover o item do Wookmark?

Comment: Já tentou usar o callback `onClosed` do Fancybox? Ele executa uma função após o Fancybox ser fechado.

Comment: Sim eu tinha dado uma lida sobre como implementa-la. Mas como eu conseguiria passar qual itemwookmark seria removido antes de atualizar todo o Wookmark?

Comment: Altere a ordem dos comandos, coloque o que fecha o fancybox antes do remove(). O fancybox irá fechar mas os outros comandos serão executados normalmente.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso. Mas depois a variavel "parent" fica undefined e não consigo alterar mais nada no elemento pai. Mesmo se tirar o parent, não acontece nada :(